# Combining Tables without JOIN using Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq

Combining Tables without JOIN keyword

```
 var res2 = from u in dtEmp.AsEnumerable()
                       from v in dtDept.AsEnumerable()
                       where u.Field<int>("DepartmentID") == v.Field<int>("DepartmentID") &&
                       u.Field<double>("Salary") > 10000
                       select new
                       {
                           Name = u.Field<string>("Name"),
                           Department = v.Field<string>("DepartmentName")

                       };
```

How to  do the same using Lambda Expression without using Join Keyword?

Comment: What do you mean 'without Join'? `where u.Field<int>("DepartmentID") == v.Field<int>("DepartmentID")` is a join, isn't it?

Comment: hmm..I meant without using JOIN keyword.

Comment: Whats wrong with `Join` keyword? You need lambda expression?

Comment: Yes, I want Lambda expression.

Comment: @Pearl- Okay! Here in query syntax you don't have  `join` keyword but thats actually a Join happening. Recollect from the old SQL days, where we use to do the same thing without`Join`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to switch from SQL syntax to Method Chain syntax? i.e:

```
var res2 = dtEmp.AsEnumerable()
    .SelectMany(u => dtDept.AsEnumerable(), (u, v) => new {u, v})
    .Where(@t => u.Field<int>("DepartmentID") == v.Field<int>("DepartmentID") &&
                u.Field<double>("Salary") > 10000).Select(@t => new
                {
                    Name = u.Field<string>("Name"),
                    Department = v.Field<string>("DepartmentName")
                });
```